# How do we set the width of the buttons in bootstrap pagination?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the pagination element of bootstrap not jump around too much because of the increasing number of digits.  However, I am not getting it to work.  I tried

```
.pagination > li {
  min-width: 50em;
}
```

with no luck

Plunkr to start, with @satya's answer https://plnkr.co/edit/dUlJUULCEcdyqkGUsRDL?p=preview

But the layout is wrong because it's left aligned.

Comment: please post code here it will be better

Comment: He already provided necessary code i think but yes we can ask for live link where he is using pagination.

Comment: I was actually in the middle of it.  But ya I do have a sample of it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.pagination > li a {
  min-width: 50em;
}
```

However 50em i think would me more.

Comment: why to give width on `<a>` width should also work on `<li>`

Comment: there's actually a problem with it, see my plunkr where the text is left aligned.